# Are there any good intranet search engines?

Tags: nfs, website, search, server-message-block, search-engine

I'm searching for a intranet search engine which is capable of spider our intranet websites **and** network shares like SMB, NFS and optionaly AFP.

Ever better for us would be a search engine which is extendable via plugins like the Spotlight framework on Mac OS X.

Does somebody know something like this? Most of the results I've found so far are only capable of spidering websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xapian Omega is amazing. And it runs on most operating systems.

[From the website:](http://xapian.org/)

> Xapian is a highly adaptable toolkit
>   which allows developers to easily add
>   advanced indexing and search
>   facilities to their own applications.
>   It supports the Probabilistic
>   Information Retrieval model and also
>   supports a rich set of boolean query
>   operators.

Then combine this with Omega, again a quote from [their site](http://xapian.org/docs/omega/overview.html)

> Omega operates on a set of databases.
>   Each database is created and updated
>   separately using either omindex or
>   scriptindex. You can search these
>   databases (or any other Xapian
>   database with suitable contents) via a
>   web front-end provided by omega, a CGI
>   application. A search can also be done
>   over more than one database at once.

It is easy to install and get working and is very fast even on large collections of files.
We use it to index a website upload directory and samba shares of ~350GB.

Answer (score 1):

There's the google search appliance.. That should do what you're after... although it might cost you an arm, leg and kidney..
http://www.google.co.uk/enterprise/gsa/index.html

Answer (score 0):

How about [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/)? When it comes to document management, it can do almost anything -- be warned, though, Alfresco is quite resource-intensive and has its own gotchas, and is not very easy to install. Or, the *installation* part is easy, it's *configuring* what makes it trickier with endless amount of buttons to click ... :-)